# Failed to run command cucumber in a spring boot jar - No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber

I'm trying to run cucumber via cucumber.api.cli.Main.main but it gives the error below (note that in IDE it works fine)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH.
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:81)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:70)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:66)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:35)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
        at br.com.xxx.service.xxx.test.TesteCucumber.main(TesteCucumber.java:17)
        ... 8 more
```

My main class

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "br.com.xxx" })
@SpringBootApplication
public class TesteCucumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        String[] arguments = {"..\\src\\test\\resources\\","-g", "br.com.xxx.service.xxx.test.cucumber.steps"};
        cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(arguments);
    }
}
```

My pom configuration

```xml
        <properties><cucumber.version>1.2.5</cucumber.version></properties>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

All dependencies are ok in the spring boot jar

[image]

I've already searched in some stack overvlow similar problems, but I got no answer

Can you help me with this error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem this way

In pom.xml I configured the maven to add the mainclass cucumber.api.cli.Main

```xml
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                  <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                  <mainClass>cucumber.api.cli.Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

I removed the TesteCucumber.class

I run mvn package

I copied all jar dependencies to the folder /lib/

I run the command line below:

```
java -jar myjar.jar --glue br.com.xxx.service.hub.test.cucumber.steps "C:\...\src\test\resources\file.feature"
```

Comment: can you please post where you created lib folder.. like inside src or at level with src